# Modelling a repetitive task list in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am trying to write  a small app for work in order to learn Meteor which is going well except I am struggling to model the data in Mongo. I seem to be trapped in RDBM mindset. I have a set of tasks that need to be completed every day with a comment stored for each task as it is done. 
I keep thinking of creating a table of tasks and then having another table with a task_id, date, status and comment fields but this seems totally against the nosql way?

I suppose I could have a document consisting of the tasks and each task having a sub document that just consists of dates and comments?

Does anyone have any ideas what would be the most effective way to model this. It's so simple but but I'm trapped in the old ways!!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think this question has more than one right answer. So take my approach as an option rather than the only solution.

If you structure your tasks like so:

tasks:

```
{
  "_id": "ObjectId()",
  "task": "string",
  "comment": "string",
  "dueDate": "date",
  "status": "string/bool/number"
}
```

Then you can easily access/filter/manipulate your data based with a single query. If you would like to separate the comment from the task, and to add it only on completion you can use two collections:

tasks:

```
{
  "_id": "ObjectId()",
  "task": "string",
  "dueDate": "date",
  "status": "string/bool/number"
}
```

comments:

```
{
  "_id": "ObjectId()",
  "taskId": "taskId",
  "comment": "string",
}
```

Now when ever you update a task in your db you can get back the taskId from it, then yo use it also to insert/update the comment.

This is just the tip of the iceberg, you can have many options if you wanna have more than one comment per task, more than one user per task, in it goes deeper.
Try to read [this article from the mongodb website](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1), might be of great help for your understanding of this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Whilst your reply didn't give me the answer I was hoping for, the article was really useful and it got me thinking and I resolved the issue by basically using a join. Turns out it is the most effective solution in my situation and fits with my oldschool headspace! :)  Thanks for taking the time to answer. When I actually get my schemas written I'll post here in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: @AntonyCastle did you ever post your schemas?